# show a list of data in react native app from sql server

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to show a list of data in my app, I already have backend API that can get the data from the server but when I trying to make it appear in my react native app, it wont appear. Below is the data that get from API
[image]

here is the code for show the data in a list view in react native apps

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,Component,onMount} from 'react';
import {View,Text, Button, StyleSheet,TextInput,ListView,ActivityIndicator,Platform} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from'@react-navigation/native';
import {StatusBar} from'expo-status-bar';

export default function StopJob(){
  const[isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(true);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
   
  return fetch('http://localhost/api/findid.php',{
    mode:'no-cors'
  })
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2)=> r1 !== r2});
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
           }, function() {
             // In this block you can do something with new state.
           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         })
  },[]);

  const Showlist=(user,job,jobid,machinecode,startTime)=>{
 
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Third', { 
 
            Userid : user,
            Job : job,
            JobId : jobid,
            MachineCode : machinecode,
            StartTime : startTime
 
          });
 
  }
  const ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
       return (
         <View
           style={{
             height: .5,
             width: "100%",
             backgroundColor: "#000",
           }}
         />
       );
  }

  if(isLoading)return(<View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}><ActivityIndicator /> </View>);
  return(
      <View style={styles.MainContainer_For_Show_StudentList_Activity}>
   
          <ListView
   
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   
            renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}
   
            renderRow={ (rowData) => <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer} 

                      onPress={this.Showlist.bind(
                        this, rowData.user,
                         rowData.job, 
                         rowData.jobid, 
                         rowData.machinecode, 
                         rowData.startTime
                         )} > 

                      {rowData.job} 
                      
                      </Text> }
   
          />
   
        </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  

  MainContainer_For_Show_StudentList_Activity :{
    
    flex:1,
    paddingTop: (Platform.OS == 'ios') ? 20 : 0,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5
    
    },

  



  

  rowViewContainer: {
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
  }

});
```

the expected output will only show the job from the database, but for now the function did not show the list view the error shown **Text strings must be rendered within a  component.**

I was referring this webpage to implement the code : https://reactnativecode.com/insert-update-display-delete-crud-operations/
on the example it show function well but when I try to implement it, it cant work :(

updated but still having same error

```
export default function StopJob(){
  const[isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(true);

  const[dataSource,setdataSource]=useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
 
  return fetch('http://localhost/api/findid.php')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           let ds = new FlatList.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2)=> r1 !== r2});
           setIsLoading(false)
           setdataSource(ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson))
     
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         })
  },[]);

  const Showlist=(user,job,jobid,machinecode,startTime)=>{
 
          this.props.navigation.navigate('', { 
 
            Userid : user,
            Job : job,
            JobId : jobid,
            MachineCode : machinecode,
            StartTime : startTime
 
          });
 
  }
  const ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
       return (
         <View
           style={{
             height: .5,
             width: "100%",
             backgroundColor: "#000",
           }}
         />
       );
  }

  if(isLoading)return(<View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}><ActivityIndicator /> </View>);
  return(
      <View style={styles.MainContainer_For_Show_StudentList_Activity}>
   
          <FlatList
   
            dataSource={dataSource}
            keyExtractor={item=>item.user}
            ItemSeparatorComponent= {ListViewItemSeparator()}
   
            renderItem={ (item) => <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer}>{item.job}</Text> }
   
          />
   
        </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: why are we using listView here rather than sectionlist? or even flatlist?

Comment: yeah it's deprecated. Use flatlist, pass your array directly as datasource.

Comment: @GauravRoy  thanks for the advice but I am new to this react native project so could u give me some example how should I change the listview to flatlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here are the steps to follow:

1. Use flatlist
2. Your data source should be a regular array. So, you can use the response from your api as it is.
3. renderRow should change as renderItem
4. renderSeparator should change as ItemSeparatorComponent

here is the final form:

```
const[isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(true);
const [data, setData]=useState([]);


 .......

  fetch('http://localhost/api/findid.php',{
    mode:'no-cors'
  })
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           //you can't use setState inside function components. :)
           setData(responseJson);
           setLoading(false);
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         })

  .......

<FlatList
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={item => item.jobid} //it should be unique. change it
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.job}</Text>}
  />
```

This should solve your issue for now but keep in mind these too:

1. Looks like you don't know differences between class components and function components. Do your research
2. Flatlist has it's own performance configurations. Research and implement them.

Comment: hi sir thanks for your example given but I also face the same error **Text string must be rendered within a <Text> component**. I have updated the code with your example on above

Comment: then if I remove ```if(isLoading)return(<View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}><ActivityIndicator /> </View>);``` this line it wont prompt the error but it also dint appear any data on screen